# xskak latex compilation very slow

Tags: compiling, xskak

I converted an annotated PGN to a block of xskak commands. However, the block below takes ~10 seconds for PDFLaTeX to compile, this way too slow! Since I have 25 games in my file, it takes 5 minutes to compile. Is there any way to significantly reduce compilation time so that my turnaround time for edits is reasonable? I'm happy to remove the \xskakcomment{} from all text if that's what's causing the problem, but there's no way for me to know which command is the bottleneck. Thanks.

```
\newchessgame[id=GameB,
    white={Huebner, Robert},
    black={Kasparov, Garry},
]

  \xskakcomment{[\%evp 0,77,25,18,27,-23,27,16,30,12,12,8,21,7,36,22,35,20,37,-2,33,38,38,29,29,29,69,18,12,-1,-4,16,29,23,23,-22,-19,0,28,20,19,19,30,-12,49,-19,-1,13,-19,-6,-6,-89,-34,-34,-34,4,17,-27,17,50,50,50,51,51,32,32,-10,0,0,0,36,-16,-33,55,55,34,46,68,74,137]}
  \mainline[style=styleC]{1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. g3 Bg7 4. Bg2 O-O 5. Nc3 d6 6. Nf3 Nbd7 7. O-O e5 8. e4 c6 9. h3 Qb6 10. c5 dxc5 11. dxe5 Ne8 12. Na4 Qa6 13. Bg5 $2  $11  }
  \xskakcomment{[\%cal Gg5e7] Threatens to trap the rook with Be7. We call thismaneuver "The Hubner" hereafter. This is a better try than Yusupov's Bf4,avoiding simplification, but does not lead to an advantage as Black has timeto strike back on the Q-side.}
  \mainline{13... b5 14. Nc3 }
  \newchessgame[newvar=GameB,id=GameB_0]\mainline[invar]{}
    \mainline{14. e6 $1  }
    \xskakcomment{Even herrer this givesWhite an advantage.}
    \mainline{14... fxe6 15. Nc3 $14  }
    \xskakcomment{With the idea of e5 and Be7.}
  \resumechessgame[id=GameB]\mainline[outvar]{} % end GameB_0
  \mainline{14... Nc7 15. Be7 Re8 16. Bd6 Ne6 }
  \xskakcomment{The bishop has entrenched itself on d6, so e5 is OKfor now, but Black can develop his Q-side with ...Qb6, ...Ba6, ...b4.}
  \newchessgame[newvar=GameB,id=GameB_1]\mainline[invar]{}
    \mainline{16... Qb6 17. a4 Ba6 $11  }
    \newchessgame[newvar=GameB_1,id=GameB_1_0]\mainline[invar]{}
      \mainline{17... b4 $2  }
      \xskakcomment{Releases control of a4.}
      \mainline{18. a5 Qb8 19. Na4 $16  }
    \resumechessgame[id=GameB_1]\mainline[outvar]{} % end GameB_1_0
  \resumechessgame[id=GameB]\mainline[outvar]{} % end GameB_1
  \mainline{17. a4 $6  }
  \xskakcomment{Realizing that Black is about to roll his pawns, Hubner triesto gain some space.}
  \newchessgame[newvar=GameB,id=GameB_2]\mainline[invar]{}
    \mainline{17. Ne2 }
    \xskakcomment{[\%cal Ge2f4] with the idea of Nf4, fighting fore6.}
  \resumechessgame[id=GameB]\mainline[outvar]{} % end GameB_2
  \mainline{17... b4 }
  \xskakcomment{[\%cal Gc3b1,Gb1d2,Gd2b3]}
  \mainline{18. Ne2 Qa5 19. Nd2 Ba6 20. f4 c4 21. Kh2 Rad8 }
  \chessdiagram{\chessboard[moverstyle=squarearrow]}{Gary cramps White again}{}
  \xskakcomment{ Fully centralizing. Black got out ofthe opening with Q-side space advantage and more active pieces.}
  \mainline{22. Qc2 $2  }
  \xskakcomment{The real struggle is for the d4 square. Nd2-f3 threatens d4 and removes theknight from pin and a tempo with .. .c3.}
  \newchessgame[newvar=GameB,id=GameB_3]\mainline[invar]{}
    \mainline{22. Nf3 c5 23. Qc2 Nb6 24. f5 b3 }
    \xskakcomment{Tempo.}
    \mainline{25. Qc1 c3 $1  $11  }
  \resumechessgame[id=GameB]\mainline[outvar]{} % end GameB_3
  \mainline{22... Nb6 23. Rfd1 Bf8 $4  $16  }
  \xskakcomment{Trading helps White,who has less space. But this also gives Hubner a critical tempo to attack.}
  \newchessgame[newvar=GameB,id=GameB_4]\mainline[invar]{}
    \mainline{23... c5 }
    \xskakcomment{[\%cal Ge6d4]}
    \mainline{24. Bf1 Rd7 25. h4 Red8 }
    \xskakcomment{Continues to turn the screws.}
  \resumechessgame[id=GameB]\mainline[outvar]{} % end GameB_4
  \mainline{24. Nf3 $1  }
  \xskakcomment{[\%cal Gf3d4] Heading for d4. Now ...c5 is too late.}
  \mainline{24... c3 }
  \newchessgame[newvar=GameB,id=GameB_5]\mainline[invar]{}
    \mainline{24... c5 $2  25. f5 Bxd6 26. fxe6 Be7 27. exf7+ Kxf7 28. Nf4 $18  }
  \resumechessgame[id=GameB]\mainline[outvar]{} % end GameB_5
  \mainline{25. Ned4 }
  \xskakcomment{Now White isthe one moving up the board.}
  \mainline{25... Nxd4 26. Nxd4 cxb2 27. Qxb2 Nc4 28. Qb3 Qb6 29. a5 Qb7 30. Bxf8 Kxf8 31. e6 $1  c5 }
  \newchessgame[newvar=GameB,id=GameB_6]\mainline[invar]{}
    \mainline{31... fxe6 32. Nxe6+ $18  }
  \resumechessgame[id=GameB]\mainline[outvar]{} % end GameB_6
  \mainline{32. e5 Qc7 33. exf7 Qxf7 34. Nc6 Rxd1 35. Rxd1 Nxe5 }
  \xskakcomment{Kasparov throws in this tactical try,but an intermezzo:}
  \mainline{36. Bd5 Bc4 }
  \xskakcomment{An intermezzo to the intermezzo?}
  \mainline{37. Qc2 }
  \xskakcomment{Calmly stepping aside while pinning the bishop to c5.}
  \mainline{37... Ng4+ $4  }
  \xskakcomment{Maybe timetrouble.}
  \newchessgame[newvar=GameB,id=GameB_7]\mainline[invar]{}
    \mainline{37... Bxd5 $4  38. Qxc5+ Kg8 39. Nxe5 $18  }
  \resumechessgame[id=GameB]\mainline[outvar]{} % end GameB_7
  \newchessgame[newvar=GameB,id=GameB_8]\mainline[invar]{}
    \mainline{37... b3 38. Qc1 Qf5 $1  39. Nxe5 Qc2+ 40. Bg2 Rxe5 $1  41. fxe5 Qxc1 42. Rxc1 Bd3 }
    \chessdiagram{\chessboard[moverstyle=squarearrow]}{Can Black holda draw?}{}
    \mainline{43. Rf1+ $3  }
    \xskakcomment{If the king moves, Rf2 stops the pawns.}
    \mainline{43... Bxf1 44. Bxf1 b2 45. Bd3 c4 46. Bc2 $18  }
  \resumechessgame[id=GameB]\mainline[outvar]{} % end GameB_8
  \newchessgame[newvar=GameB,id=GameB_9]\mainline[invar]{}
    \mainline{37... Nxc6 38. Qxc4 Qc7 39. Qxc5+ Qe7 $16  }
    \xskakcomment{Whiteis still better, chances to win the b-pawn.}
  \resumechessgame[id=GameB]\mainline[outvar]{} % end GameB_9
  \mainline{38. hxg4 Re2+ }
  \newchessgame[newvar=GameB,id=GameB_10]\mainline[invar]{}
    \mainline{38... Bxd5 39. Qxc5+ }
  \resumechessgame[id=GameB]\mainline[outvar]{} % end GameB_10
  \mainline{39. Qxe2 Bxe2 40. Bxf7 Bxd1 41. Bc4 b3 42. Nxa7 b2 43. Ba2 Be2 44. Kg2 Bd3 45. Kf3 Ke7 46. Ke3 b1=Q 47. Bxb1 Bxb1 48. Nb5 Kd7 49. a6 Kc6 50. f5 $1  }
  \xskakcomment{gf gf Bf5 Nd6! domination.}
\mainline[outvar]{} % end GameB
```

Comment: xskak is slow, at first because it does a lot of parsing and storing, and at second because it is quite old and uses slow commands (e.g. from the ifthen package). One would have to rewrite large parts from scratch to improve that. You can save time by preprocessing a game and save it to a file, see "Exporting the games".

Comment: This worked, however redefining ```\renewcommand\xskakendgamedata
{\xskakset{id=\xskakcurrentgameid}%
\xskakgetgame{white}--\xskakgetgame{black}:
\printchessgame[style=styleB,level=1]
\par\bigskip}
\input{xskakgames.xsk}''' as in the docs only results in printing the main line, i.e., the game. How can I have it print all the comments and variations in the order of the commands that I exported into the .xsk file?

Comment: sorry but don't ask new questions in a comment. As a new question instead.